# SSL: Can't convert DER to PEM

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I'm working with ssl certificates and trying to convert myCA.cer to myCA.pem...

```
$ openssl x509 -in myCA.crt -inform der -outform pem -out myCA.cer.pem
unable to load certificate
65927:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1341:
65927:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:385:Type=X509
```

Why? What's wrong?

Comment: Are you even sure that the input is DER and not already PEM? DER is just completely binary while PEM is base64 with some prefix and suffix which indicate the type of data. The extension itself does not affect the type of data inside the file.

Comment: Thanx for reply! How can I check it for sure?

Comment: open the file inside an editor, do a hexdump... . DER is binary while PEM is text.

Comment: You are right! For some reason it was already a text(PEM)… weird. Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx to Steffen Ullrich, I've finally found the reason of that error... The myCA.crt was already in PEM format, as DER is binary file while PEM is base64 encrypted text.