# Error Converting .DER file to .PEM file

Tags: command-line, encryption, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to convert [this file](http://politicas.icpbrasil.gov.br/PA_AD_RB_v2_3.der) in DER format to PEM.

Using openssl.exe utility (tried in versions 0.98.1 and 1.02 of openssl) I tried the following commands:

`openssl x509 -inform der PA_AD_RB_V2_3.der -out PA_AD_RB_V2_3.pem`

`openssl pkcs7 -inform der PA_AD_RB_V2_3.der -print_certs -out PA_AD_RB_V2_3.pem`

`openssl rsa -inform der -in PA_AD_RB_V2_3.der -out PA_AD_RB_V2_3.pem`

All of them return the following errors:

`16196:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:./crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1294: 16196:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:./crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:830: 16196:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:./crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:749:Field=type, Type=PKCS7`

Of course there are some differences between commands but the message is the same.
I couldn't figure out what encryption the DER file is encoded, that's why Itried different commands.

Is something wrong in DER file? Or I messed up somewhere in the commands?

My final goal is to pass the PEM file to the `-certfile` parameter in `smime -sign`

Comment: I already checked these two questions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1015792/ssl-cant-convert-der-to-pem) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1287238/issue-converting-der-certificate-files) but it didn't help... also tried to use pkcs8 tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These tools you tried aren't generic "DER to PEM" converters. All of them work with files in very specific formats, for example `openssl x509` wants to be given an X.509 certificate and nothing else. But ASN.1 DER is a very generic format (just like XML or JSON); it's indeed used for X.509 certificates, but it's also used for a hundred of other different things.

The file you have is neither X.509 certificate nor a PKCS#7 message – it is a "trust list" or "signing policy" in the [RFC 3125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3125) format, which OpenSSL doesn't know what to do with. So even if you converted it to PEM using `base64 -e`, your next command would still fail due to the format being unrecognized.

(It's certainly possible to make a tool that would convert *any* DER file to PEM, because "PEM" format is *literally* Base64 of the same DER file, plus the begin/end headers of course. But if it does not consist of a X.509 certificate, then it makes no sense to use it as a `-certfile` regardless of the format.)

I don't know of any apropriate tools for working with RFC 3125 signature policies, but looking at it with `openssl asn1parse` and `dumpasn1`, the policy seems to include these **two** X.509 certificates:

- http://acraiz.icpbrasil.gov.br/credenciadas/RAIZ/ICP-Brasilv5.crt
- http://acraiz.icpbrasil.gov.br/credenciadas/RAIZ/ICP-Brasilv2.crt

It will be easiest to download the individual certificates directly from these URLs.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to sign a file in PKCS7 format, runinng the `smime -sign` tool did sign my file but it doesnt have the attribute for the signing policy. I'm using a validator that checks the signature and it says is valid (showing which certificate I used as a signer) but it expects this signing policy to be there as well... now I realize I need to look more into it

Comment: Does it want the entire policy file, or does it want just its OID?

Comment: It says "the PKCS7 package doesn't have the attribute: 1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.15..  I think it only wants the OID

Comment: That might be the `openssl smime -policy` option? The OID specified inside your .der file is `2.16.76.1.7.1.1.2.3`.

Comment: Tried to use the `-policy` option with both OIDs but to no avail... it seems in the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-smime.html) this option is to be used with `-verify` so it has no effect in `-sign`. I will try openssl 1.1  cms tool it has the `-cades` option to choose the signing certificate

Comment: The OID you posted was the attribute type; the other one was to be the attribute's value.